# [Admob]How to allocate the 'new' house ads to serve for 'only unfilled request'?

Tags: android, admob, ads, inventory, promoting

The 'new' AdMob house ads are taking away the normal ads inventory.

The house ads should only served for unfilled requests.

- After upgrading to new house ad, my ratio between normal admob ads /
  house ads has been around 50:50 or 60:40 at best.
- I tried setting the CPM(of the house ad) to 0 but the result is the
  same.
- Tried disabling the house ad completely. The result is 80-90% fill
  rate for normal admob ads.

Please let me know how to fix this.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use AdWhirl and fill AdMob with MillenialMedia and ZestAdz instead.